# facebook v4 sdk class thrwoing error T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in file FacebookSession.php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to use facebook v4 sdk for login. When I call the  function it generates following error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in /Facebook/FacebookSession.php on line 93
```

I checked the file and found this is the function that throws error

```
public function getSessionInfo($appId = null, $appSecret = null)
  {
    $targetAppId = static::_getTargetAppId($appId);
    $targetAppSecret = static::_getTargetAppSecret($appSecret);
    return (new FacebookRequest(
      static::newAppSession($targetAppId, $targetAppSecret),
      'GET',
      '/debug_token',
      array(
        'input_token' => $this->getToken(),
      )
    ))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphSessionInfo::className());
  }
```

But I am not able to understand what is wrong in this .

Can any one help me out please 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely not using PHP 5.4+. The PHP SDK 4.x requires a PHP Version greater than or equal to 5.4 - many providers did not upgrade yet, unfortunately. You need to ask your provider if he is willing to upgrade, or use the older PHP SDK 3.x (not recommended).

Comment: so what should I do to upgrade in my server ?. Or is it a way to find out what version I am using in the website?. The examples runs absolutely fine in the localhost of my computer

Comment: you need to ask your provider if he is willing to upgrade. of course it works on localhost, i assume you have a newer version of php on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

`(new Object())->method()` was not valid syntax in older versions of PHP